# Expand UIView with pan gesture in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I want to implement a view that stays at the bottom of the screen and can be expanded with a pan gesture just like in the Uber app for iOS? 
[Uber Home screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02iHS.jpg) The view will be minimizable when dragged downwards

Comment: What have you tried already?  Please post your work in progress implementation.

Answer (score 1):

There are few third party libraries which makes your work easy. This is one of it. [LNPopUpController](https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNPopupController).

Or else, if you want to customise the code and write: Take one view controller and add a UIView on top of it. Now add Pan Gesture to view like below.

```
func handlePan(pan : UIPanGestureRecognizer) { 

   let velocity = pan.velocityInView(self.superview).y //; print("Velocity : \(velocity)")

    var location = pan.locationInView(self.superview!) //; print("Location : \(location)")

    var movement = self.frame
    movement.origin.x = 0
    movement.origin.y = movement.origin.y + (velocity * 0.05) //; print("Frame.y : \(movement.origin.y)")

    if pan.state == .Ended{
        print("Gesture Ended")
        panGestureEnded()
    }else if pan.state == .Began { print("Gesture Began")
        let center = self.center
        offset.y = location.y - center.y //;  print("Offset.y : \(offset.y)")


    }else{ print("Gesture else")
        animator.removeBehavior(snap)

        // Apply the initial offset.
        location.x -= offset.x
        location.y -= offset.y

        //print("location.y : \(location.y)")

        // Bound the item position inside the reference view.
        location.x = self.superview!.frame.width / 2

        // Apply the resulting item center.
        snap = UISnapBehavior(item: self, snapToPoint: location)
        animator.addBehavior(snap)


  }


}
```

Comment: what is doing in `panGestureEnded` method?